# Winforms user control class accessible by all application

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture

I'm creating a Winforms application that needs a control class to manage all app components.

I was thinking about a class that inherits from `Component`, glued in the main form of the application.

How could I access this control class from any point of my application? Which is the correct way to do this?

Or should I change my mind about this architecture?

Comment: What you're planning to do with that class?

Comment: Title not so clear `Winforms user control class`? so you want to inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`?, `accessible by all application`? you want to access in Multiple Applications?

Comment: Inherited from System.ComponentModel.Component, as a non visual component. The idea is access this component from any point of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Static class` or `Single Instance class` and use allover your application.

Note: static class should inherit from `System.Object` so using that way it is not possible to inherit from `Component` If you really require to derive from `Component` you can go for Single instance approach.

Check out [Singleton Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: I think that this will resolve my problem. Thanks for your answer, @Sriram.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should take in mind that having a control glued into your main form will force you  keep the main form alive during the entire user experience, otherwise you will lose the instance of your control class.
Having that said, you will probably be better off creating a static Class that manages the app components, and, a control that calls your manager class' methods. Having your manager class as a static class will allow you access its methods without the need of an instance.
Hope this helps you out!
Cheers